# Unable to indentify the issue here

Tags: python

Currently working on a portfolio code, and I am trying to print an array but I keep getting hit with

```
w = np.random.random((1000, len(symbols)))
w = (w.T / w.sum(axis=1)).T
print(w[:5])
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-23-246da7acc0b7>", line 3, in <module>
   print(w[:5])

 File "C:\Users\godso\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 1506, in _array_str_implementation
   return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "")

 File "C:\Users\godso\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 712, in array2string
   return _array2string(a, options, separator, prefix)

 File "C:\Users\godso\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 484, in wrapper
   return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\godso\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 510, in _array2string
   format_function = _get_format_function(data, **options)

 File "C:\Users\godso\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 431, in _get_format_function
   formatdict = _get_formatdict(data, **options)

 File "C:\Users\godso\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 403, in _get_formatdict
   fkeys = [k for k in formatter.keys() if formatter[k] is not None]

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I have the symbols defined and all I am trying to do is the print the code below, note I have way more code but I didn't include it because everything worked fine up until now.

```
w = np.random.random((1000, len(symbols)))
w = (w.T / w.sum(axis=1)).T
print(w[:5])
```

Comment: The issue is that you have a set but presumably expected to have a dictionary.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, I can post the full code I am also following along with a textbook.

Comment: The code you have shown does not seem to have anything to do with the error, because it involves neither a set nor a `keys` attribute.

Comment: Would it be better if I provided the full code, + the textbook I am following?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated the question with the full traceback.

Comment: It would be better if you created and showed a [mre].

Comment: You seem to have deleted some of the error traceback. Can you put it back in again?

Comment: That is not the full error traceback.  There should be an actual error message at the bottom.

Comment: I've edited it again, the error I am getting is the attribute error.

Comment: Did you use this function somewhere? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Comment: Yes i did, np.set_printoptions(precision=5,suppress=True,
                    formatter={"float: lambda x:f'{x:6.3f"})

Comment: Well. That's a set, not a dictionary.

Comment: Perhaps `formatter={float: lambda x:f'{x:6.3f}'}`? As mentioned, you created a set with the single string `"float: lambda x:f'{x:6.3f"` in it instead of a dictionary.

Comment: I understand that but I am following along from a textbook and it works, https://prnt.sc/wex135

Comment: Notice that the error is in `formatter.keys()`. That's the formatter you set with set_printoptions.

Comment: Yup, I noticed that was my error, I apologize I have started learning python a week ago and have continuously make these type of errors. I appreciate all the help.